# Why is the output of this programm garbage?

Tags: c, pointers

I am wondering why the output is garbage? And how can I solve this problem?

```
#include<stdio.h>

char *Func(void);
int main()
{
    char *string1;

    string1 = Func();
    puts(string1);

    return 0;
}

char *Func(void)
{
    char string2[10]="medo";
    return string2;
}
```

Comment: You need to explain your question a little better.

Comment: `string2` is allocated on the stack, not heap, so as soon as `Func()` exits, the standard does not guarantee that those bytes won't immediately be overwritten by something else.

Comment: If you want to change the contents of the string inside the function pass a char* (with enough memory allocated) to the function and change it there

Answer (score 2):

Because `string2` is only valid in the scope of `Func`.

An array decays into a pointer when assigning it to a pointer, passing it to a function or when used with `return` in a function returning a pointer.

An array decaying into a pointer means that it is converted to a pointer and the pointer points to the first element of the array.

With an array like this:

```
int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

These are equivalent:

```
int *p1 = arr;
int *p2 = &arr[0];
```

The problem with `Func` is that it is returning a pointer that points to a memory location that is only valid while `Func` is running. Once `Func` returns, it is no longer valid and the program flow might replace these values immediately.

In your `main` function you pass this pointer to `printf` and because the location where `string1` is pointing to isn't valid in `main` (it was only valid in `Func`), you get garbage. Actually that is undefined behaviour, and *medo* could have been printed as well.

How to fix it: declare an array in `main`, pass it to `Func`, let `Func` use the
passed array and return:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

Func(char* string2);
int main()
{
    char string1[20];

    Func(string1);
    puts(string1);

    return 0;
}

void Func(char *string2)
{
    strcpy(string2, "medo");
}
```

Comment: You have to use `char *` as the parameter to `Func`

Comment: @aaaaaa123456789 ups, I forgot to type the `*`. Thanks for the feedback, I've updated my post

Comment: It's better to use `const char *` in my opinion since `Func` does not mutate the string.

Comment: @Pablo you got the return type in the prototype definition wrong too :P

Comment: And while we're at it: `strcpy` is unsafe, it's better to use `strncpy`.

Comment: @d3L the function _does_ mutate the string! What do you think `strcpy` is doing there?

Comment: @aaaaaa123456789 Ah you're right. Got the classic "I want to copy a string to another location" problem in my head.

Comment: @d3L it well no, `Func` mutates the string. If you change it to `const char*`, then gcc complains with *‘strcpy’ discards ‘const’*

Comment: I made a quick copy & paste of the OP without looking around what else was there, so I missed that in the OP's code was a prototype definition of `Func`. I fixed the code.

Comment: @Pablo Shit happens! Anyway, good explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

Because the lifetime of the string has already ended by the time you print it.

Local variables, such as `string2` in `Func`, are often stored in the stack, which is a very dynamic structure that changes every time a function is called or returned. (The actual behavior of the program stack is a bit too complex to elaborate here, but keep in mind that stuff in the stack doesn't survive the function that puts it there.)

By the time the function returns, `string2` is no longer necessary, and thus it might be overwritten with garbage data. Nevertheless, `Func` returns a pointer to `string2` (remember that the name of an array is a pointer to its contents) — thus returning a pointer to the stack-allocated string that is being overwritten with garbage data. Printing the data referenced by this pointer (in `main`, via `string1`) just prints that garbage.

There are two ways of solving this issue. One is to let the caller handle memory allocation, and pass the allocated area to the callee, like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void Func(char *);

int main (void) {
  char string[10];
  Func(string);
  puts(string);
  return 0;
}

void Func (char * string) {
  strcpy(string, "test");
}
```

...and another way is to let the callee handle the allocation, but remembering that the caller must free it, like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * Func(void);

int main (void) {
  char * string = Func();
  puts(string);
  free(string);
  return 0;
}

char * Func (void) {
  char * string = malloc(10);
  strcpy(string, "test");
  return string;
}
```

Either way would solve your issue, and which one you choose is a matter of design.